# Is CyanogenMod Installer compatible with my Note 2 after updating it to Android 4.3?

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-note-2, samsung-knox

Can I install CyanogenMod on Samsung Galaxy Note 2 after I updated it to Android 4.3? Will knox interfere? How can install it using the installer of CyanogenMod or with the conventional way?

Answer (score 0):

Some people have successfully [installed CyanogenMod on top of 4.3 (with Knox)](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/85592-has-anyone-slayed-the-samsung-knox-android-43-dragon/).

Refer to the [official installation guide](http://beta.download.cyanogenmod.org/install), which includes installation on the phone and on the PC.

Comment: Thanks for that. I feel better now that some tried and succeeded. I will still do some research though. Maybe someone tried it on Note II and can share his experiences with us.